# BarChart has incorrect partial Graphics elements?

Tags: graphics, charts

I'm trying to create a bar chart that displays job evaluation ratings visually. Rather than use a bar, I'd like to show each rating number as a discrete unit, a rounded rectangle. As per Mathematica help files, you can use any Graphic as a Chart Element, good. But even in their examples, the partially rendered objects are not accurate.

```
data = {Tooltip[7, "testing"], 7.7, 5, 9, 3.3};
BarChart[
 data,
 PlotLabel -> "Name",
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 Ticks -> None,
 BarSpacing -> 0,
 LabelingFunction -> After,
 ChartElements -> Graphics[{
    LightBlue,
    Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .3]
   }],
 ChartLabels -> {"Communication", "Collaboration", "Timeliness", 
   "Prof. Dev.", "Habits of Mind"}
 ]
```

[image: Resulting bar chart]

It *does* seem to work with Graphic3D objects like spheres, but only if the Viewpoint is not adjusted.

[image: Using Graphic3D Spheres works better, but not the look I'm going for]

I have looked into Scaling Functions for the graphics with little success. Any way to get the look of the first with the accuracy of the second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ChartElements -> {Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .3]}], {1, 1}}`:

```
BarChart[data, PlotLabel -> "Name", BarOrigin -> Left, Ticks -> None, 
 BarSpacing -> 0, LabelingFunction -> After, 
 ChartElements -> {Graphics[{LightBlue, Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .3]}], {1, 1}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {"Communication", "Collaboration", "Timeliness", 
   "Prof. Dev.", "Habits of Mind"}]
```

[image]

[`ChartElements >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartElements.html):

[image]

```
Multicolumn[
 Table[Labeled[
   BarChart[data, PlotLabel -> "Name", BarOrigin -> Left, 
    Ticks -> None, BarSpacing -> 0, LabelingFunction -> After, 
    ChartElements -> {Graphics[{LightBlue, 
        Rectangle[RoundingRadius -> .3]}], wh}, 
    ChartLabels -> {"Communication", "Collaboration", "Timeliness", 
      "Prof. Dev.", "Habits of Mind"}, ImageSize -> 300], wh, Top], 
    {wh, {{1, 1}, {1, All}, {All, 1}, All, {1, 1/2}, {1/2, 1}}}], 
  2, Appearance -> "Horizontal"]
```

[image]